# I want to use Clang on Windows to compile 64 bit code from C++ - Getting stdio.h file not found

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, clang

I have installed the 64 bit MinGW, and put it into the C:\MinGW path. With the 32 bit MinGW I could compile OK, but then when I changed to the 64 bit version, to compile to 64 bit code, I still had problems, getting this error message:

```
test1.cc:1:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
```

I have run this command to try to compile my example:

```
clang test1.cc -o test1.exe -v --target=x86_64
```

Comment: Two problems: The first is that you need to install, or use an already installed, standard library. The second problem is that you are compiling C++ code, for which you should use the command `clang++`.

Comment: I'd been using a standard library before, but I'm not sure if it's going to be the same in both 64 bit and 32 bit.

Comment: I'd previously managed to compile and run a C++ program using `clang` rather than `clang++`, to my surprise. Maybe it was in fact a C program, but I don't think it was.

Answer (score 0):

Using the below command fixed the issue for me

```
clang test1.cc -o test1.exe -v --target=x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
```

Comment: If OP is relying on MinGW to provide the standard library, they probably want a MinGW-flavored target. Something like `--target=x86_64-w64-mingw32`.